what is *(*(*p))) pointer in C?
I need print 5 from data using p3 but I don't know what it is.
I managed to find out printf("%d,", *(*(*(p3))+4)); is the answer but I still don't how does it works.
I could guess (*p3)[3][2] is pointing 6 from dat[0][3][2]
I'm beginner and don't to where to dig in first.
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int dat[2][3][2] = { 
        { 
            {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} 
        },
        {
            {7, 8}, {9, 19}, {11, 12}
        } 
    };
    int *p1, *p2, (*p3)[3][2];
    p3 = dat;

    printf("%d,", *(*(*(p3))+4)); //this is the answer  it prints 5

    return 0;
}


Specifically p1 = dat is invalid C. Maybe just remove p1 and p2 since they are unused anyway?

See What should main() return in C and C++?. The short answer is int — void is allowed by Microsoft on Windows, but you certainly shouldn't use void as the return type on any other platform (and I'd argue you shouldn't use it on Windows either, but that's more a matter of opinion).

*(*(*(p3))+4) is an invitation to errors.  It should never appear outside of a teaching context.  Use subscript notation rather than stacking up the asterisks and parentheses like that.

It is highly questionable whether *(*(*(pd))+4) should ever appear in a teaching context!

First, you should know the rule about arrays in expressions. An array in an expression is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element except when:

it is the operand of sizeof,
it is the operand of unary &, or
it is a string literal used to initialize an array.

Then we can evaluate  *(*(*(p3))+4):

p3 is a pointer to an array of 3 arrays of 2 int.
(p3) is the same thing.
*(p3) is the thing that p3 points to, so it is an array of 3 arrays of 2 int.
(*(p3)) is the same thing.
(*(p3)) is an array but is not in one of the exceptions above, so it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Now it is a pointer to an array of 2 int. (The is the first array of 2 int in the 3 arrays of 2 int.)
*(*(p3)) is the thing that the pointer points to, so it is an int. (It is the first int in the first array of 2 int in the 3 arrays of 2 int.)
*(*(p3))+4 adds 4 to that pointer. This nominally yields a pointer 4 int beyond where the pointer points. Technically, the behavior is not defined by the C standard because the arithmetic goes beyond the array immediately containing this int. That array is only 2 int in size, so adding 4 goes beyond it.
(*(*(p3))+4) is the same thing.
*(*(*(p3))+4) nominally produces the int that the pointer points to. As noted above, this is technically not defined by the C standard, but a common behavior is to produce the int that is in memory 4 int beyond the start of p3, which is 5.


I appreciate for your help. I was almost gave up about it, You saved my day. thanks again.


(*p3)[3][2] p3 is pointer to 2d array of 3 rows and 2 colums
p1 = dat; Assigns an array of 2D arrays to this pointer (nD arrays in C are arrays of arrays)
*(*(*(p3))+4)) invokes undefined behavior as it is the same as dat[0][0][4] and the last index is outside the permitted range

basically:

*(p3) == dat[0]
*(*(p3)) == dat[0][0]
*(*(*(p3))+4)) == dat[0][0][4]


Unfortunately, evaluating dat[0][0][4] (or the OP's equivalent expression) has undefined behavior.

@JohnBollinger What did I write in my answer? (third bullet from the top)


I managed to find out printf("%d,", *(*(*(p3))+4)); is the answer but I still don't how does it works.

This ...
    int /* ... */ (*p3)[3][2];

... declares p3 as a pointer to an array of 3 arrays of 2 int.
As for *(*(*(p3))+4),

First, observe that (p3) is equivalent to p3, so we can simplify to *(*(*p3)+4)

Second, dereferencing a pointer to an array yields the array, but in most contexts, lvalues of array type, such as the aforementioned, are automatically converted to pointers to their first elements.  Thus,

the assignment p3 = dat assigns p3 to point to the first element of dat, corresponding to the initializer

{ 
    {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} 
},



dereferencing p3 once yields that array, which immediately is converted to a pointer to its first element, an array of 2 int corresponding to the initializer {1, 2}

derferencing that result yields that array, which is immediately converted to a pointer to its first element, an int object containing the value 1.  Suppose we call this pointer p.



Expressions of the form *(x + y) are equivalent by definition to x[y] and y[x].  The form with * is more fundamental, but the [] forms are easier for most people to read.  Whichever the form, *(p + 4) attempts to yield the int at index 4 in the int array into which p points.

BUT WAIT: p points to an array of only two int.  4 is not a valid index into this array.  You can imagine that the program might ignore this, and simply yield an int that is four int-sized units past *p, but the language does not specify that it must be so.  The behavior is in fact undefined, and therefore, it might really not yield 5.  That it does yield 5 for you, in your particular experiments is immaterial.


Thus, given ...

I need print 5 from data using p3 but I don't know what it is.

... I would not accept your answer.  The most natural solution is simpler.  For instance, I would probably go with
printf("%d,", (*p3)[2][0]);

That says "element 0 of element 2 of the [array] object to which p3 points". Note among other things how (*p3)[2][0] mirrors the declaration of p3.  It is possible to rewrite that without using the [] operator (**((*p3) + 2), say), but that just obfuscates.

p3 is &dat[0], so p3[0][2][0] is the same as dat[0][2][0].
In general, for a pointer p and index i, p[i] is equivalent to *(p + i) (which may need extra parentheses around p and i if they are not simple identifiers). So working inwards to replace array index operators with indirection operators, p3[0][2][0] is equivalent to *(p3[0][2] + 0), which is equivalent to *(*(p3[0] + 2) + 0), which is equivalent to *(*(*(p3 + 0) + 2) + 0), which can be simplified to **(*p3 + 2).
OP's *(*(*(p3))+4) is equivalent to *(*(*(p3 + 0) + 0) + 4). So working outwards to replace indirection operators with array index operators, *(*(*(p3 + 0) + 0) + 4) is equivalent to *(*(p3[0] + 0) + 4), which is equivalent to *(p3[0][0] + 4), which is equivalent to p3[0][0][4]. However, p3[0][0][4] is outside the bounds of the array p3[0][0] which has dimension 2, leading to undefined behavior.  Logically, p3[0][0][4] would be at the same location as p3[0][2][0] because array elements are stored contiguously, so several implementations will just return the value at that location even though the behavior is technically undefined.

void main() this is not the prototype of main() but if you use this way at least do not write
    return 0;

Your compiler should have told you about, like this:
    orig.c(15): warning C4098: 'main': 'void' function returning a value

Enable all warnings.

I'm beginner and don't to where to dig in first.

Consider at first writing the code this way:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int dat[][3][2] =
    {
        [0] =
        { {1, 2},
          {3, 4}, 
          {5, 6} //[0][2][0], [0][2][1]
        },

        [1] = 
        {
            { 7,  8},
            { 9, 10},
            {11, 12} //[1][2][0], [1][2][1]
        }
    };
    return 0;
}

This is good for you to see what is being loaded in memory. Note that the first dimension is optional, since dat is an array of int[3][2] and every occurrence is identical.
Writing this way makes it clear that dat[0][2][0] is 5.
use your IDE
As an example, you can see in Microsof's VS Code the address of dat:

and use the pointer address to see the array in memory like here

Note the values from 1 to 12=0x0C
in C a declaration binds a name with a type
Religion and coding standards are here to stay. But in C we declare a variable as being a container for a thing of a type. Compiler does not care about space. People does care.
These lines are all equivalent:
    int*p0=NULL;
    int                   *                     p1 = NULL;
    int*                           p2 = NULL;
    int                            *p3 = NULL;

But p0, p1, p2 and p3 are of the same type: int*. So the 3rd line
    int* p2 = NULL;

is the real thing: we are declaring p2, a name, as int*, a type. If p2 is int* of course *p2 is int. It is called a de-reference, and it is like we see for p3 above.
No coding convention will change this.
back to the code: an example

    int (*pInt32)[3][2] = (int(*)[3][2]) dat;
    //int (*pInt32)[3][2] = &dat;
    printf(
        "(*pInt32)[2][0] = %d\n", (*pInt32)[2][0] );  // this prints 5
    printf(
        "*(*(*(pInt32)) + 4 = %d\n", 
            *(*(*(pInt32)) + 4));  // this also prints 5


This is the declaration of dat:
    int dat[][3][2] = {};

So dat is an array. Each dat[] is int[3][2] as we see at the program above. We have dat[0]  and dat[1].
If we want pInt32 as a pointer to an array of int[3][2] we need the parentheses, due to the precedence of the [] operator over the * operator. Without them we would have an array of pointers and not a pointer to an array.
This could also be initialized to just &dat instead of (int(*)[3][2]) dat but the second way seems to be closer to the fact.
Each *pInt32 is an array of int[3][2] so [2][0] is the correct position, as we see in the delcration of dat.
    int (*pInt232)[2][3][2] = (int(*)[2][3][2]) dat;
    printf(
        "(*pInt232)[0][2][0] = %d\n", (*pInt232)[0][2][0] );  // this also prints 5
    printf(
        "*(*(*(pInt232)) + 2 = %d\n", 
            *(*(*(*(pInt232)) + 2)));  // this also prints 5

pInt232 is also the same thing: a pointer to an array. pInt232 and pInt32 points to the same address, the one of dat.
As pInt232 points to the same type of array as dat we can use bracket notation to print the 5 at the same index as in dat.
dat is an array of int after all

    int (*pInt) = (int*) &dat;
    printf(
        "*(pInt + 4)= %d\n", 
            *(pInt + 4));  // this also prints 5

So we can use pointer arithmetic and look at the 5th adrress and get the same 5.
more on the  *(*(*(*(pInt232)) + 2)) line


`pInt232` is `int (*)[][3][2]`



 so `*pInt232` is `int [][3][2]`



 so `*(*pInt232)` is `int [3][2]`



 so `*(*(*pInt232))` is `int [2]`



 so `*(*(*(*pInt232)))` is `int`



 but the `5` is in the 3rd `int[2]` array, so its address is  *(*(*(*(pInt232)) + 2)) as `C` have pointer arithmetic.



complete code for the example
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int dat[][3][2] =
    {
        [0] =
        { {1, 2},
          {3, 4}, 
          {5, 6} //[0][2][0], [0][2][1]
        },

        [1] = 
        {
            { 7,  8},
            { 9, 10},
            {11, 12} //[1][2][0], [1][2][1]
        }
    };

    int*p0=NULL;
    int                   *                     p1 = NULL;
    int*                           p2 = NULL;

    printf("in the array, dat[0][2][0] = %d\n\n", dat[0][2][0] ); 

    int (*pInt32)[3][2] = (int(*)[3][2]) dat;
    //int (*pInt32)[3][2] = &dat;
    printf(
        "(*pInt32)[2][0] = %d\n", (*pInt32)[2][0] );  // this prints 5
    printf(
        "*(*(*(pInt32)) + 4 = %d\n", 
            *(*(*(pInt32)) + 4));  // this also prints 5

    int (*pInt232)[][3][2] = (int(*)[][3][2]) dat;
    printf(
        "(*pInt232)[0][2][0] = %d\n", (*pInt232)[0][2][0] );  // this also prints 5
    printf(
        "*(*(*(pInt232))) + 2 = %d\n", 
            *(*(*(*(pInt232)) + 2)) );  // this also prints 5

    int (*pInt) = (int*) &dat;
    printf(
        "*(pInt + 4)= %d\n", 
            *(pInt + 4));  // this also prints 5

    return 0;
}

output f the example
(*pInt32)[2][0] = 5
*(*(*(pInt32)) + 4 = 5  
(*pInt232)[0][2][0] = 5 
*(*(*(pInt232))) + 2 = 5
*(pInt + 4)= 5

